# Не могу заменить числа на значения из TextBox

Tags: c#, webforms

Есть строка в которой есть значения (cell16+cell17+cell18).
Мне нужно поменять на значения из TextBox.
    Пыталась так, получилось у cell с 1 до 9, 
начиная с 10 он просто меняет первое значение из 10 число 1 и .т.д. 
Как это законтрить?P.S. WebForms

````
    ```
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Connect.query))
         {
           OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandText = "Select * from CAT ORDER BY ID_CAT";
           conn.Open();
           OracleDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (rd.Read())
           {
              if (rd[3].ToString() != "")
              {
               string id = rd[0].ToString();//порядковый номер строки
               string str = rd[3].ToString();//сама формула e.g.(cell1+cell2)
               for (int i = 1; i < Table1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                 if (str.Contains("cell"))
                 {
      str = str.Replace("cell" + i + "", ((TextBox)Table1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text);
                 }
                else
                 {
                       break;
                 }
                                }
                 Expression e = new Expression(str.Replace(",", "."));
                 double result = Convert.ToDouble(e.Evaluate());
                 string sad1 = result.ToString("#0.00##").Replace(".", ",");
                 for (int i = 1; i < Table1.Rows.Count; i++)
                  {
                    for (int j = 4; j < Table1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                        {                 ((TextBox)Table1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(id)].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text = sad1;
                        }
                   }
       }

    ```
````

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос к более читабельному. Исправь сдвиги кода, установи больше коректных меток, сделай коментарии куда смотреть. Помоги другим людям помочь тебе.

Comment: Вроде стало лучше

Comment: А что это `WinForms` или `WPF`? И это не понятно `(TextBox)Table1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text`, `Table1` - это что за контрол такой? Да, у ридера есть полезные методы: `rd.GetString(0)` или `rd.GetInt32(1)`

Comment: это WebForms, а это (TextBox)Table1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text Это значение из таблицы i-номер строки, j- номер ячейки где есть textbox, а в нем значение

Comment: Я понял, что вам нужно поменять что-то в строке содержащей формулу, но вот что и как нет. Нужно уточнить на примере: формула имеет значение такое-то, ячейка в таблице имеет такое-то значение, требуется получить на выходе такое-то новое значение в формуле. Как то так, иначе ничего не понятно.

Comment: У пользователя есть формула(cell1+cell2+cell15) цифры после cell означает цифру строки. И когда я пыталась поменять Replace-ом меняет только первую цифру, то есть cell15 он меняет на 5 игнорируя что это десятки

Comment: И дальше... что требуется получить на выходе?

Comment: на выходе нужно cell15 поменять на значение из  (TextBox)Table1.Rows[15].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text

Comment: `cell15 он меняет на 5` ну все верно. Первой же итерацией цикла у вас при Replace входной параметр `cell1`. Вот и из строки `cell15` он и заменяет на `[значение Table1.Rows[1]]5`. Вам необходимо отделять куски `sell` по знаку плюс (парсить иными словами). И проходить циклом не по кол-ву строк, а по кол-ву sellX. Я вижу решение вашей задачи так

Comment: Массив cell-ов?